# Extracting particular nested values within dictionary

Tags: python, json, distinct-values

Sorry if my wording is wrong. I have no training in python.

I requested a JSON and can manually pull the data I want. I know there is a better way to request the data I want and was looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Here is what I have(I included just a part of the JSON as it long):

```
>   This is the example of the JSON that I am requesting.
  {"games": {
>       
>           "0":{
>     "id":"371749","gameUID":"1213028","sport":"Football","league":"NCAA","sportsbook":"BetOnline","startDate":"2020-10-29T23:30:01Z","awayRotationNumber":"103","homeRotationNumber":"104","awayTeam":"South
> Alabama","homeTeam":"Georgia Southern","description":"South Alabama vs
> Georgia
> Southern","isLive":"0","gameMoneylineAwayPrice":"+165","gameMoneylineHomePrice":"-190","gameSpreadAwayHandicap":"+4","gameSpreadHomeHandicap":"-4","gameSpreadAwayPrice":"-110","gameSpreadHomePrice":"-110","gameTotalPoints":"52","gameTotalOverPrice":"-110","gameTotalUnderPrice":"-110","gameTeamTotalAwayPoints":"24","gameTeamTotalAwayOverPrice":"-110","gameTeamTotalAwayUnderPrice":"-120","gameTeamTotalHomePoints":"28","gameTeamTotalHomeOverPrice":"-115","gameTeamTotalHomeUnderPrice":"-115","halfMoneylineAwayPrice":"+140","halfMoneylineHomePrice":"-160","halfSpreadAwayHandicap":"+3","halfSpreadHomeHandicap":"-3","halfSpreadAwayPrice":"-115","halfSpreadHomePrice":"-105","halfTotalPoints":"26","halfTotalOverPrice":"-115","halfTotalUnderPrice":"-105","periodMoneylineAwayPrice":"+135","periodMoneylineHomePrice":"-155","periodSpreadAwayHandicap":"+0.5","periodSpreadHomeHandicap":"-0.5","periodSpreadAwayPrice":"-105","periodSpreadHomePrice":"-115","periodTotalPoints":"10","periodTotalOverPrice":"-135","periodTotalUnderPrice":"+115","changedDate":"2020-10-29T14:31:16Z","checkedDate":"2020-10-29T15:13:33Z"}
>     ,"1":{(same as 0 etc etc...}

res = requests.get("myurl")

data = res.json()

game_one = data['games']['0']['awayTeam'] + " vs " + data['games']['0']['homeTeam'] + " " + data['games']['0']['gameSpreadHomeHandicap'] + "  "

game_two = data['games']['1']['awayTeam'] + " vs " + data['games']['1']['homeTeam'] + " " + data['games']['1']['gameSpreadHomeHandicap'] + "  "

game_three = data['games']['2']['awayTeam'] + " vs " + data['games']['2']['homeTeam'] + " " + 

ticker = game_one + game_two + game_three + game_four
output = open(r'E:\output.txt', 'w')
output.write(ticker)
output.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may work (if you have questions about code - ask them):

```
games = []
for game in data['games']:
    for info in data['games'][game]:
        v1 = data['games'][game]['awayTeam'] + ' vs '
        v2 = data['games'][game]['homeTeam'] + ' '
        v3 = data['games'][game]['gameSpreadHomeHandicap']
    games.append(v1 + v2 + v3)
    
with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(' '.join(games))
```

Comment: So this prints everything in the format except for its in a vertical list. How would I make it all on one line. 

I am trying to output this to an led matrix so as they scroll like a ticker.

Comment: @cc2644  wow! I edited the script so that it does that or at least it should

Comment: @cc2644 actually I changed the script even more so its shorter (should still work)